# Creating Tables with Columns having mulitple values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I've got an assignment to run some SQL queries on a table looking like this: 
T1 
C1| C2 | C3 
x1| y1 | z1 
x2| y2 | z2

But I'm not sure how to create the table in SQL.

Comment: You can find the create table syntax here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html - or did you have some specific issue with this?

Comment: Check out this link: [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp). They provided simple explanations of SQL statements. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure is the right way to design the tables?

It look like a simple Master/Detail model

Probably your T1 table is the master

On the second table (C) put a column with reference ID to the main table

The do the query with a simple Join or Left Join